# Dynamic routes array initializing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to initialize the array of Routes dynamically by some external metadata. More specifically, what I want to achieve is something like this

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
    // ...some other routes...
    {
       path: `${externalMetadata}`,
       loadChildren: () =>
          import(`./pathToModule/${externalMetadata}.module`).then( m => m.SomeModule)
    }
  ]
```

My questions are:

1. This is the right approach?
2. I was able to achieve this behaviour, but sometimes I receive compilation error with

> .ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is
> in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

and when I replace the `${externalMetadata}` from import module path, recompiles with success (which is weird).

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing this issue

> .ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is
> in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

the solution is to add into **files** array from  **tsconfig.app.json** file the paths to every module file you want to load it dynamically.

As an example, consider the following array of routes:

```
//app-routing.module.ts
const routes : Routes = [
 {
        path: '',
        /* Because we are using dynamic import module declaration, we have to declare every lazy loaded
        module into tsconfig.app.json files array in order to let compiler know about them.*/
        loadChildren: () =>
          import(
            `./${getModulePathBySomeLogic()}/${getModuleFileNameBySomeLogic()}.module`
          ).then(m => m[`${getModuleClassNameBySomeLogic()}Module`])
      },
]
```

now all we have to do is to update the **files** array from **tsconfig.app.json** file with every path we will have dynamically loaded. For example:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "preserveWhitespaces": false
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts",
    "app/some-module1/some-module1.module.ts",
    "app/some-module1/some-module1-routing.module.ts",
    "app/some-module1/some-module2.module.ts",
    "app/some-module1/some-module2-routing.module.ts",      ],
  "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

**Note:** if you have your routes logic and module logic into different ts files you have to add both into **files** array.